# How to select points which are below (under) polygon in 3D?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcscene, select-by-location

I have two layers. Points are (point z) shape and polygon is (polygon z) shape.
I would like to select only point which are under polygon. Look at picture, On the first one you can't see points which are under polygon, on a second one I turned off polygon layer(all points are visible).

Is it possible to convert polygon to some kind of volume(object) and then use select by location (contain the source layer feature) in 3D?
Any other ideas?

[image: picture of points and polygon in ArcScene]

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it but in ArcGIS 10.3 with the 3D Analyst extension there is a tool called [Inside 3D](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000072000000). It appears to create a Table which you could relate back to your point table and pass a selection through?

Comment: I dont have closed 3D object, i have only polygon feature class with Z-coordinate

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying the point and polygon feature classes have Z-coordinates, and you want to (a) *select by location* all points that intersects the polygons, then (b) *select from current selection* only points that have a Z-coord lower than that of the intersecting polygon's Z-coord... is this correct? If so, you can expose the Z-coords of the points and polygons by [Adding XY Coordinates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm), and use a normal *select by attribute* with the "Z-coord" field in lieu of an actual *select by location* query to get the points lower than their intersecting polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Do a spatial join with the points as the target layer. That way you will get the z attributes of the polygon in the same layer as the points. Then you can select by attributes all the points where the Z-value from the polygon layer is higher than the Z-value from the point layer.

Comment: I have done that, but it is partly correct. This way I have found only points which are higher(or lower) of MIN or MAX Z coordinate of polygon.

Comment: Ok then it isn't clear to me (from your question) what you want.